# No 'SPI-Provider' Manifest header

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

When trying to install my application as an osgi bundle with the *install* command in karaf on the command line, everything seems fine. When I then type *start (id)* everything still seems fine, but my application does not seem to accept requests. When I then type *log:display*, I get this:

```
2016-04-20 13:49:38,251 | INFO  | Thread-19        | bundle                           | 37 - org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle - 1.0.1 | Bundle Considered for SPI providers: oms-integrations
2016-04-20 13:49:38,251 | INFO  | Thread-19        | bundle                           | 37 - org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle - 1.0.1 | No 'SPI-Provider' Manifest header. Skipping bundle: oms-integrations
```

I'm new and I have no clue what this means ("No 'SPI-Provider' Manifest header.") or how to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a problem. It just means that you have Aries spi-fly installed. It scans all bundles for this header and enhances the ones with the header to be able to use the ServiceLoader in OSGi. If you do not use ServiceLoader then you can safely ignore these messages.

You can also configure this logger to WARN to suppress the messsages.

Comment: But it also says: "Skipping bundle: oms-integrations", which is my bundle.

Comment: Yes. It says this about almost all bundles. It just means that it did not find the header that would trigger the enhancement.